# Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'UISearchBar'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I'm working to make an app that will allow someone to enter text into the search bar, and the app will automatically open "https://www.example.com/ (text from search bar).

I keep getting Failed Builds and an error about Multiple inheritance from classes `UIViewController` and `UISearchBar`.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBar {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
        {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            if let url = URL ("https://www.doughnationgifts.com/",doughnationcode)
            let doughnationcode = String(searchBar.text!)
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to extend `UISearchBar`? Why is the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method inside the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: Is there another method I should have used? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don´t need the `UISearchBar` inheritance, this extends from `UIViewController` already. You might want to add the `UISearchBarDelegate` instead. But then you also need to add an outlet to your `searchBar` to be able to set the delegate.

Also, you can´t add a function inside your `viewDidLoad`.

Do it like this instead:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        if let url = URL ("https://www.doughnationgifts.com/",doughnationcode)
        let doughnationcode = String(searchBar.text!)
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm no longer getting the initial error, now I just need to work through the rest.